# Nodejs template system documentation

Tags: node.js, templates, dsl, templating-engine, unsupervised-learning

I want to create my own template system for node.js (just for educational purposes), but I can't find any useful information to start with. Are there any good tutorials out there which could help me?
Thanks!

Comment: node itself doesn't impose any requirements on template systems. Some of the common frameworks built on it (e.g. Express) do have specific protocols for how a template processor can communicate with the framework. You might take a look at widely-used template systems and see how they do it. Offhand, I'm not convinced that re-inventing the wheel is the best way to learn something, but if you want to, I'll make a selfish suggestion (which will be a very tall order): Try to implement DTL (Django Template Language) in a way that doesn't require Dojo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/docs/) docs would be a good place to start. A [breakdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467150/1113772) of how it's used to build a [parser](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jison-build-parsers-in-javascript) for [the CoffeeScript grammar](http://coffeescript.org/v1/annotated-source/grammar.html) may be helpful in seeing the big picture.

**References**

- [npm: An UriTemplate implementation of rfc 6570](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uritemplate)